# is there any IIS setting require for url rewriting?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url, url-rewriting

i have used URL rewriting using global.asax file. url rewriting is working file on local machine but when i made it online its not working.

void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(Request.PhysicalPath).ToLower();

```
if (File.Exists(Request.PhysicalPath))
{
    if (extension == ".html")
    {
        Response.WriteFile(Request.PhysicalPath);
        Response.End();
    }
    return;
}

var path = Request.Path;

if (!Context.Items.Contains("ORIGINAL_REQUEST"))
    Context.Items.Add("ORIGINAL_REQUEST", path);

if (extension == ".html")
{
    var resource = UrlRewriting.FindRequestedResource();
    var command = UrlRewriting.GetExecutionPath(resource);
    Context.RewritePath(command, true);
}
```

}

url is:ind205.cfmdeveloper.com
when you click on about us ,demo,advertise page it will not display.
so please let me know is there any IIS setting require,

reply me soon
thanks
Samir

Answer (score 0):

I work on url rewriting. I don't think it need any setting in IIS as i work in it and i didn't made any changes in url writing by the way you can see these links.hopefully you get any solution from them.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/517/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms/

http://www.asp.net/learn/Videos/video-154.aspx

http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/030522.htm

http://urlrewriter.net/

If you got your answer from these links check my answer and also vote it.thanx

Comment: hi emy,
        i have already seen these sites but its not my solution.i am not able to identify my problem.i dont think so there is requirement of setting on IIS.but still i am confusing...

Comment: in my opinion you use http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/download this link to download url rewriter and implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have .html file that you check for. For html to pass from asp.net processing , you need to declare it (map it) ether on iis ether on web.config